# The 'InitializeComponent' fails compiling WPF with csc.exe

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I know that this problem was posted several times on StackOverflow. And I already checked these posts but can't figure out the error in my program.
I downloaded a simple WPF HelloWorld program and tried to compile it with the command-line tool:

csc.exe /out:WPFApplication.exe /target:winexe App.cs MainWindow.cs /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationFramework.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\WindowsBase.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationCore.dll"

But I only got the error message "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context".

Here's the App.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace HelloWorld
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class App : Application
  {
  }
}
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="HelloWorld.App"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld"
  StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"/>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace HelloWorld
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

and MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="HelloWorld.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Icon="app.ico">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
      Hello, World!
    </TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You can't use csc alone to compile an application if you have markup. You need to use msbuild on a project file. There are msbuild tasks to process the markup and generate cs files which msbuild then invokes csc to compile.

Comment: Simply open the project in the free Visual Studio Community edition and you're all set.  Click the debug or build solution button.

Comment: I created a .cproj file and then used the MSBuild task now and it works perfect!